# R code not able to recognise escape character

Tags: r, escaping

I am writing an R script through Javascript and then running the file

```
    Connection.eval("try(logs<-source(\"" + rcodeFile + "\",print.eval=TRUE),silent=TRUE)");
```

But whenever there is a new line, it is being converted to \n and R server is throwing unexpected input error.

Comment: Try it with \\ - the escape character needs an escape character

Comment: it is still not able to parse it. After i escape, outvar = as.numeric(invar)+2\\ncat(\\\"string:\\\", outvar) is the string i finally get but it still throws the same error

Comment: Try using single quotes inside the expression rather than escaped double quotes... `Connection.eval("try(logs<-source('" + rcodeFile + "',print.eval=TRUE),silent=TRUE)");`

Answer (score 0):

Did the single quotes work for you or are you still having a problem?

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava helped